# In Win10 can a Storage Space 2-way Mirror be the System disk?

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-10-pro

I promised to set up SW RAID Mirroring for my client.  The computer came with a 500GB HDD as the only disk (with Win10 Pro installed on it).  I just plugged in 2 additional new 500GB SSDs (not yet formatted).  Can I create a Storage Pool from the 2 SSDs and make it into a 2-way mirror.  Then reinstall (or preferably move) the OS to that Storage Space Mirror and do away with the existing HDD and have it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Windows 8 onto a Storage Spaces Pool](https://superuser.com/questions/467529/can-i-install-windows-8-onto-a-storage-spaces-pool).  The answer to the duplicate applies to all versions of Windows that supports Storage Space Pools.  Strictly speaking, Storage Spaces isn't actually a software RAID.

Comment: @JoeC - that should be the answer - i.e. no, not unless you have a UEFI driver to read the storage space.